# Vue Passing Data from component to another component

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex

I am making a "create account" flow for user and I am not able to pass data from one component to another. The first component has radio buttons with options of "tenant", "landlord", "contractor". Once the user selects "tenant", then the data should pass to the next step where they fill out a form with name and all that good stuff.. once they submit, it should all go together to the back end.

`acc-for.vue` with radio buttons component below.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <v-app
      style="background-image: url('https://blog.modsy.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/D2_Full.jpg')"
    >
      <v-container class="pa-12">
        <v-row>
          <v-card class="pa-16">
            <v-card-title>
              Are you a?
            </v-card-title>
            <v-radio-group v-model="selectedValue" @change="selectedAcc">
              <v-radio
                v-for="account in accountType"
                :key="account.name"
                :value="account.name"
                :label="account.name"
              ></v-radio>
            </v-radio-group>
            <v-row>
              <v-btn rounded color="black" class="white--text" href="/login"
                >Back</v-btn
              >
              <v-btn
                rounded
                color="black"
                class="white--text"
                @click="selected(accountSelected)"
                >Next</v-btn
              >
              <!-- href="/create-acc" -->
            </v-row>
          </v-card>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-app>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { mapMutations } from "vuex";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      selectedValue: false,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    accountType() {
      return this.$store.state.accountType;
    },
    selected() {
      return this.$store.state.selectedAccType;
    },
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapMutations(["SELECTED_ACCOUNT_TYPE"]),

    selectedAcc(e) {
      this.$emit("selected-accountType", e);
    },
  },
};
</script>
<style></style>
```

`createAccount.vue` this component has the form for the `fName` and `lName` and all that good stuff..

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <v-app
      style="background-image: url('https://blog.modsy.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/D2_Full.jpg')"
    >
      <v-container class="pa-12">
        <v-row>
          <v-card class="pa-16">
            <v-card-title>
              {{ selectedTypeUser }}
            </v-card-title>
            <v-form>
              <v-text-field
                class="pa-4"
                type="text"
                v-model="newUser_fName"
                label="First Name"
              />
              <v-text-field
                class="pa-4"
                type="text"
                v-model="newUser_lName"
                label="Last Name"
              />
              <v-text-field
                class="pa-4"
                type="text"
                v-model="newUser_email"
                label="Email"
              />
              <v-text-field
                class="pa-4"
                type="text"
                v-model="newUser_password"
                label="Password"
              />
              <v-row>
                <v-btn rounded color="black" class="white--text" href="/acc-for"
                  >Back</v-btn
                >
                <v-btn
                  @click="registerUser"
                  rounded
                  color="black"
                  class="white--text"
                  >Next</v-btn
                >
              </v-row>
            </v-form>
          </v-card>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-app>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { mapMutations } from "vuex";
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      newUser_fName: "",
      newUser_lName: "",
      newUser_email: "",
      newUser_password: "",
    };
  },

  methods: {
    ...mapMutations(["ADD_USER"]),
    registerUser() {
      let config = {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      };
      axios
        .post(
          "http://localhost:7876/createUser",
          {
            fName: this.newUser_fName,
            lName: this.newUser_lName,
            email: this.newUser_email,
            password: this.newUser_email,
          },
          config
        )
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response.statusText);
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log("Error: ", e.response.data);
        });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

`store.js` (state) is below

```js
// import vue from "vue";
import vuex from "vuex";
import axios from "axios";
import Vue from "vue";

Vue.use(vuex, axios);

export default new vuex.Store({
    state: {
        users: [],
        accountType: [
            { name: "Tenant" },
            { name: "Landlord" },
            { name: "Contractor" }
        ],
        selectedAccType: [],
    },
    mutations: {
        ADD_USER: (state, payload) => {
            state.users.push(payload.user);
        },
        SELECTED_ACCOUNT_TYPE: (state, payload) => {
            state.selectedAccType.push(payload)
        }
    },
    actions: {
        addUser: ({ commit }, payload) => {
            commit("ADD_USER", payload);
        },
        selectAcc: ({ commit }, payload) => {
            commit("SELECTED_ACCOUNT_TYPE", payload)
        }
    },
    // getters: {
    //     addAccountType(state, e) {
    //         state.accountType.push(e)
    //     },
    // },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I see this on the button:

```
<v-btn rounded
            color="black"
            class="white--text"
            @click="selected(accountSelected)"
            >Next</v-btn
          >
```

But I'm not finding a method with that name in your attached code. Double check that your names are all matched up and that you are calling the correct function on the click event.

Comment: the name stuff is in the other component with the form. @jonnycraze

Comment: Is the problem that things are not getting saved into your state?

Comment: YES! i think so. Then i need to get it on the form and send it to the back end.. the state is not updating

Comment: The reason your state is not updating is because you never call SELECTED_ACCOUNT_TYPE anywhere. You have mapped it, but you never call it. You need to call that method and pass it the selectedValue. Also, if you haven't yet, I'd encourage you to install the Vue extension for chrome developer tools - it will help you inspect your components, as well as your state objects.